# Facebook fetcher C# console application

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am new at facebook sdk so asking very basic question. I need to fetch user information from Facebook in C# console application. I have created one Application in Facebook.com/developer and set its type to "Native/Desktop" and have its AppID as well as Secret Key. I have also downloaded Facebook C# SDK 5.4.1.

Now I am not sure, how to proceed, I tried to fetch all my feeds using following code.

```
FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient("AppID", "Secret Key");
var result = client.Get("me/feed");
```

But get exception "**(OAuthException) An active access token must be used to query information about the current user**."

After some research I find out that I will have to get Access Token so I used following code to get access token

```
string url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APPID&client_secret=SECRETKEY&grant_type=client_credentials";
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string token = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

so I get response (in token) like this "access_token=322232329253232323|323233riZZZZZZZ_3p1BdHf3232332323k"
So now I tried like this

```
FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(token.Replace("access_token=", ""));
        var feeds = client.Get("me/feed");
```

But still get the exception "**(OAuthException) An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.**

Can anyone please guide me, how to proceed and fetch the information.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is just a C# console application, the easiest way to access Facebook is probably via PowerShell and http://facebookpsmodule.codeplex.com. This will get you past the nitty-gritty of the Facebook API.

Comment: Thank you Jon for your response and sorry for late follow up. I downloaded and explored PowerShell but I am afraid I could not find any suitable help that how to use it in C# Console application and fetch information from facebook. Can you please point out to me any useful material on it?

Comment: Start with
Import-Module Facebook
Get-Command -Module Facebook

Comment: Jon, actually I don't know how to use these commands? Should I use Command Prompt? FacebookPSModule setup has one Facebook.dll but when I add reference of it in my project, it have almost same functions like SDK dll have. Please give me some detail or example code. I will be very thankful.

Comment: I can't really give a complete primer on Windows PowerShell in this space. If you just run powershell.exe you will get a prompt where you can run these commands. http://powershell.org is a good starting place for Windows PowerShell information.